# where can I find DOSBox for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emulation, dosbox

I want to add DOSBox to my website. I know it's possible because of playdosgamesonline.com, which uses js to emulate, I just don't know how to do it, cause when I look for it it's nowhere to be found. Does anyone know where to get it?

Comment: You could try getting the source for dosbox  https://github.com/Camano/DOSBox and compiling with https://emscripten.org

Comment: https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Unofficial_ports#JavaScript

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsdosbox/

Comment: yes, i did. i googled, but nothing came up for dosbox in anyway shape or form for web browsers, html, js, or online

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this codepen I made. Just upload a ZIP and give it a .EXE to execute: https://codepen.io/killroy/pen/zRgLjM

It is basically this (using https://js-dos.com/cdn/js-dos-api.js):

```
document.getElementById('zip')
    .addEventListener('drop', event => zipUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.dataTransfer.files[0]));
document.getElementById('start')
    .addEventListener('click', event => {
        exeName = document.getElementById('exe').value;
        zipUrl =  URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('zip').files[0]);
        if(exeName === '' || zipUrl === '') return alert('Please enter .EXE name and .ZIP file');
        dosbox = new Dosbox({
            id: "dosbox",
            onload: dosbox => dosbox.run(zipUrl, exeName),
            onrun: (dosbox, app) => {
                console.log("Starting: '" + app + "'");
                document.getElementById('fullscreen').style.display = 'auto';
            }
        });
        dosbox.ui.overlay.hide();
        dosbox.ui.showLoader();
        dosbox.downloadScript();
    });
document.getElementById('fullscreen')
    .addEventListener('click', event => dosbox.requestFullScreen());
```

Answer (score 0):

(supposed to be a comment but i dont have reputation)
https://github.com/dreamlayers/em-dosbox is a compiled version of it to js, original repo that @Keith gave was deleted.